# How to Add button to HeroCard and select the value when clicking on it

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I have implemented a carousel of Hero Cards to display all the Schedules a perticular Doc can have. In the hero cards i have added a button to select a Particular schedule. Below is the code

```
private async Task ShowSessionsHeroCard(IDialogContext context)
    {
        var replyToConversation = context.MakeMessage();
        replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
        replyToConversation.Attachments = await GetSessionHeroCard(context);
        //replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(GetSessionHeroCard());
        await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
    }

    private async Task<List<Attachment>> GetSessionHeroCard(IDialogContext context)
    {
        List<Attachment> list = new List<Attachment>();
        List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
        foreach (var sessionDetails in scheduleList)
        {
            string[] session = GetSplittedDetails(sessionDetails);

            hospitalName = session[0]; //Hospital Name: {0}
            availableDay = session[1]; //Available Day: {1}
            appointmentNo = session[2]; // Appoinment No: {2}
            sessionAvailable = session[3]; // Session: {3}

            HeroCard hero = new HeroCard()
            {
                Title = hospitalName,
                Subtitle = availableDay,
                Text = sessionAvailable + appointmentNo,
                Buttons = cardButtons
            };

            list.Add(hero.ToAttachment());

        }

        CardAction getSessionValues = new CardAction()
        {
            Value = hospitalName + availableDay + sessionAvailable + appointmentNo,
            Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
            Title = " Select Appointment "
        };

        cardButtons.Add(getSessionValues);

        string selectedAppointment = getSessionValues.Value.ToString();
        await GetSelectedAppointment(context, selectedAppointment);

        return list;
    }

     private async Task GetSelectedAppointment(IDialogContext context, string sessionSelected)
    {
        var replyToConversation = context.MakeMessage();
        //replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.List;

        string[] result = Utility.SplitSelectedApoitmentString(sessionSelected);
        var heroCard = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = "Appointment Schedule",
            Subtitle = "These are the Appointment Details",
            Text = "Hospital selected : " + result[0] + "\n" + "Day of Appointment : " + result[1] + "\n" + "Time of Appointment : " + result[2] + "\n" + "Appointment Number" + result[3],
        }.ToAttachment();

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
        {
            Content = heroCard.Content,
            ContentType = heroCard.ContentType
        };
        replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);

    }
```

My questions are

1. Am i defining the Button Correctly?
2. The CardAction getSessionValues is getting some values even before i click 
   on the button. How to avoid that.
3. How to get the selected card value and pass it to another method.

I cant figure out whats wrong here please help. (Am sure Am doing sumthing very stupid.)

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Do you receive an error? If so, please tell us by editing your question. what does `await GetSelectedAppointment(context, selectedAppointment);` do?

Comment: It calls to another method where i pass the selected selection and want to display it in another HeroCard. I dont get any errors in the second method. i cant get the selected herocard values am always getting the same value whatever card i select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to follow your code and it's not clear who is calling the `GetSessionHeroCard` method, however, I think you have a misunderstanding about how to work with cards.

The general steps you need to follow when using cards with buttons are:

1. Create the card, with the card actions
2. Add the card as an attachment to the reply message the bot will be sending to the user
3. Wait in X method (it could be on MessageReceivedAsync or in a new method) with `context.Wait`. This is key because this method is the one that will receive the message with the value once the button is clicked.

You can check the [RichCards](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-RichCards) sample and the [Contoso Flowers](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers) sample so you can see that in action.

Comment: hi, i have added the full code in the question by editing it. please c whether now u could follow. I will try what you said too.

Comment: I just read the code and I think that my suggestions are ok. You are doing `await GetSelectedAppointment(context, selectedAppointment);` while creating the HeroCard and that's wrong. The selected value will need to happen after the user clicks the button

Comment: Thanks your answer showed me the way. I Followed your suggestions and now its working fine.